# Splitting a string in a special way

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `str = "3 (15 ounce) cans black beans"`. I want to split it into several pieces, split by the parenthesis term. The result should be like:

`['3', '(15 ounce)', 'cans black beans']` keeping the parenthesis.

How can I achieve this goal using a regular expression in Python?

Comment: data is impotant for regex - got more data? post it.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: What about nested brackets, what did you try yourself?

Comment: Can you have nested, unbalanced and escaped brackets as well? If not then use: `re.findall(r'\([^)]*\)|[^()]+', str)`

Comment: Anubhava, thanks my friend, I've been spending a lot of time on this staff. Really it worked perfectly! I didn't thought about re.findall, I was blind by the other post using re.split.

Comment: according to pythex  `(\d+) +(\(.+\)) ?(.*$)`  should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try using re.split() with [()] as the regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "3 (15 ounce) cans black beans"
>>> re.split(r'[()]', s)
['3 ', '15 ounce', ' cans black beans']
>>> 

>>> help(re.split)
```

EDIT:

To keep the parenthesis, you could do the following:

```
>>> re.search(r'(.*)(\(.*\))(.*)', s).groups()
('3 ', '(15 ounce)', ' cans black beans')
>>>
```

Comment: he wnats to keep the ( ) - yours discards it

Comment: Seems that `re.split` has a bug preventing zero-width matches from working, or you'd be able to use `re.split(r'(?=\()|(?<=\))', s)` (as you can in Perl).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as Anubhava suggest it the solution is to use `re.findall(r'\([^)]*\)|[^()]+', line)`

```
line = '3 (15 ounce) cans black beans, drained and rinsed'
a = re.findall(r'\([^)]*\)|[^()]+', line)
```

`print(a)` gives

```
['3 ', '(15 ounce)', ' cans black beans, drained and rinsed']
```

exactly what I wanted, Thanks for the ones who tried to help me :)

Comment: `re.split(r'(\([^()]*\))', s)` or `filter(None, re.split(r'(\([^()]*\))', s))`